# Onchange event by name attribute

Tags: javascript

When an alement has an `id` or `class` you can easily add a `change` event in Javascript:

```
'change #bla': function(e) {
  // do something
}
```

But I have an element with only a `name` attribute:

```
<select name="bla">
  // options
</select>
```

How can I trigger the change event on this element?

Comment: What framework are you using? Declaring a property is not how you listen to events normally.

Comment: I'm not sure I recognise the syntax in your first snippet of code - are you using some library like jquery ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'change [name="bla"]'` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the attribute selector

```
$('change [name=bla]') // matches exactly 'bla'

$('change [name^=bla]') // matches those that begin with 'bla'
```